# Python Convert/Verify 5 or 6 Digit Int as a valid Time

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, time

This is Homework. I have a function that needs to recieve a 5 or 6 digit integer "setStart(clock)" . I need to verify that the integer correpsonds to a value for a valid time. The actual homework states :
Parameter 1:  "clock" is a 5- or 6-digit integer in the format HMMSS or HHMMSS, where H is the 1- or 2-digit hour of the day past midnight, MM is the 2-digit minute past the hour, and SS is the 2-digit second past the minute.  Mandatory.  Arrives unvalidated.  Example:  104200 represents 10:42:00am; 150910 represents 3:09:10pm

I have tried converting to Strings and checking the length which works fine unless the integer entered has leading zeros such as 000130 (which should be valid), but only has a length of three. I attempted some of the datetime.datetime functions and time. functions but those require FULL time values not just HH MM SS.

Someone please let me know what I am missing!

Please note that clock is an integer and not a string

I tried:

```
def setStart(self, clock):
    # Verify Clock is an integer
    if type(clock)!= int:
        raise ValueError("stadiumJumpScore.setStart:  Start time must be an integer") 
    # Verify Length of clock and Valid HH MM SS values

    #attempt 1
    # Failed with leading Zeros
    '''
    test = str(clock)
    testa = test[-2:]
    print testa
    testb = test[-4:-2]
    print testb
    print "NEXT ITERATION"
    '''
    # removed OTHER FAILED ATTEMPTS, KEPT LAST ONE because it is the "workflow" I need
    # attempt 12
    #failed with leading Zeros
    '''
    if clock.__str__().__len__() == 5:
        HH = str(clock)[0:1]
        MM = str(clock)[1:3]
        SS = str(clock)[3:5]            
    elif clock.__str__().__len__() == 6:
        HH = str(clock)[0:2]
        MM = str(clock)[2:4]
        SS = str(clock)[4:6]
    else:
        raise ValueError("stadiumJumpScore.setStart:  Check Length of start time")
    # Use Values from above converted back to int for calculation
    intHH = int(HH)
    intMM = int(MM)
    intSS = int(SS)

    if intHH > 23 or intHH < 0:
        raise ValueError("stadiumJumpScore.setStart:  Hour is invalid or out of range")
    if intMM > 59 or intMM < 0:
        raise ValueError("stadiumJumpScore.setStart:  Minute is invalid or out of range")
    if intSS > 59 or intSS < 0:
        raise ValueError("stadiumJumpScore.setStart:  Seconds is invalid or out of range")

    seconds = intHH*60*60+intMM*60+intSS
    return seconds
    '''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it's within the bounds of your assignment, you should let `datetime` do the heavy lifting for you.

```
try:
    datetime.strptime(clock,'%H%M%S')
except ValueError as e:
    #raise whatever exception you want here, or reraise
```

Note that you do NOT need a "full time value" to do this.  Anything that is a valid [format string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) will work.

Comment: You rock, Had to tweak it a bit, but you put me on the path. I was trying to post the revised code a few times for others, hopefully I will get it right this time.

    `try:
            midnight = datetime.datetime.strptime('000000','%H%M%S')
            myTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(clock),'%H%M%S')
            tdelta = myTime - midnight
            seconds = tdelta.total_seconds()
            return seconds
        except:
            raise ValueError("stadiumJumpScore.setStart:  Start time is invalid")`